# How to check in-app purchase android on server side GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, in-app-purchase, marmalade

I need to check the purchase status on my server (Google app engine).

My android app use Marmalde and s3eAndroidMarketBilling for buying in-app purchase but the only thing I can send to my server is the RequestID.

The problem is I dont find tuto/example that explain how to check in-app statut.

Thanks